# Docker syntax error end of file unexpected

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hello im new in docker and im having problem to build this:

MySQL install well

PhpMyadmin instal wel...

but in apache i have this error

error:

```
: not foundbin/pete_install.sh: 2: 
/usr/local/bin/pete_install.sh: 110: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
```

pete_install.sh

Line   1 to 10

```
#!/bin/bash 

FILE=/var/www/html/.installed
if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]; then
  
echo "#######################################"
echo "Starting WordPress Pete installation..."
echo "#######################################"

rm -rf /var/www/html/Pete4
```

Linea 99 to 110

```
FILE=/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]; then
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
fi

chmod 600 -R /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 -R /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

apachectl -DFOREGROUND
#systemctl start
#/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
echo "Loading apache..."
```

full file https://pastebin.com/1f5a3pJY

Comment: Is there a "fi" to match the "if" in line 4?

Comment: Hi, yes in line 85, i added the full file in pastebin

Comment: Please include enough details to demonstrate the issue _in the question itself_, not behind a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of time, the error causes because you write your script on windows, the line break on windows is `\r\n`, while on linux it's `\n`.

You should install some tools to change format, e.g.:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y dos2unix
$ dos2unix /usr/local/bin/pete_install.sh
```

Comment: Holy crap, I just spent about an hour trying to solve this same thing... thanks!